# Symfony4 : Problem with KnpSnappy/WkHtmlToPdf

Tags: php, symfony, twig, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I am trying to set up a pdf file generation system. To do this, I came to use WkHtmlToPdf as well as the KnpSnappy Bundle.
Here's what i did :

1 - I have first downloaded a precompiled binary (MacOs) https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

2 - Then installed the bundle : `composer require knplabs/knp-snappy` (https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy )

3 - And finally add the bundle in bundles.php with `Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle::class => ['all' => true],`

This is what I wrote in my function, inside my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/pdf/{id}", name="room_pdf", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
 */
public function pdf(Room $room, \Knp\Snappy\Pdf $knpSnappy)
{  

  $knpSnappy->setOption("encoding","UTF-8");
  $filename = "mypdf";
  $html = $this->renderView('room/show.html.twig' , array(
      'room' => $room,
  ));

  return new Response(
     $knpSnappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
  200,
  array(
     'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
     'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'.pdf"'
  )
);
```

I have made several tests, when I try to generate a pdf with an URL or a piece of HTML code I do not encounter any problem, but when I try to generate a pdf based on a twig view using renderView I end up with a pdf of 1777 pages including 1775 blank

Does anyone have an idea of ​​what can be done?

Edit : 
I fixed the 1777 pages by loading correctly my css . I add this code at the beginning of my template :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% for path in encore_entry_css_files('app') %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(path) }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

So I end up with a page, almost formatted. My app.js file doesn't seem loaded so I don't have all valid bootstrap resources in my pdf

This is what my terminal tells me :

```
Feb  5 21:52:37 |INFO | SNAPPY File "/var/folders/gv/0qb9br_15gggjmhg5zs_qtth0000gn/T/knp_snappy5e3b390a547d50.44491512.pdf" 
has been successfully generated. stderr="Loading pages (1/6)\n[>                                                           ] 
0%\r[======>                                                     ] 
10%\r[=======>                                                    ] 
12%\rWarning: 
Failed to load file:///build/runtime.js (ignore)         
\nWarning: Failed to load file:///build/vendors~app.js (ignore)
\nWarning: Failed to load file:///build/app.js (ignore)
\n
```

I added that at the end of my template :

```
{% block scripts %}
    {% for path in encore_entry_css_files('app') %}
        <script src="{{ absolute_url(path) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And now my console terminal look like that

```
Feb  5 22:21:42 |INFO | SNAPPY File
"/var/folders/gv/0qb9br_15gggjmhg5zs_qtth0000gn/T/knp_snappy5e3b3fd843af90.61904670.pdf"
has been successfully generated. stderr="Loading pages (1/6)\n
```

But it seems that my bootstrap is not loaded yet.. 
(It is declared in my app.js with " require('bootstrap'); ")

Comment: what happens if you stick the url that renders that twig view in? also, could it be the main template isnt rendering with the css and js in the head section? what is the rendered $html before you send to the pdf thing?

Comment: I tried, but ii have this error "failed to load" my URL as I am working in local. I used var_dump($html) it returns me a "string(9586)" . Here's what the terminal says  
 "/var/folders/gv/0qb9br_15gggjmhg5zs_qtth0000gn/T/knp_snappy5e3b146a888ee8.77314197.pdf" has been successfully generated. stderr="Loading pages (1/6)\n[>] 0%\r[======> ] 10%\r[=======>] 12%\rWarning: Failed to load file:///build/app.css (ignore)  \nWarning: Failed to load file:///build/runtime.js (ignore)\nWarning: Failed to load file:///build/vendors~app.js (ignore)\nWarning: Failed to load file:///build/app.js (ignore)\n

Comment: looks like it doesn't have the site root folder defined, file:///build/etc would look for folder /build in the root of the hard drive